# How can I get the total number of pages on Spring Data?

Tags: java, pagination, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have an Angular app that shows a list of entities and I have a 'show more' button that increments page number and uses this method:

```
Page<myEntity> result = myRepo.findByAttr(attr, page);
```

I format this `result` and send it via REST's JSON. I want to disable 'show more' button if there's no further pages to get. There's a 'frameworkie' specific way to retrieve this number or I should use `findAll()` and count through this list?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the source code of `Page` interface

```
public interface Page<T> extends Slice<T> {

    /**
     * Returns the number of total pages.
     * 
     * @return the number of total pages
     */
    int getTotalPages();

    /**
     * Returns the total amount of elements.
     * 
     * @return the total amount of elements
     */
    long getTotalElements();

    /**
     * Returns a new {@link Page} with the content of the current one mapped by the given {@link Converter}.
     * 
     * @param converter must not be {@literal null}.
     * @return a new {@link Page} with the content of the current one mapped by the given {@link Converter}.
     * @since 1.10
     */
    <S> Page<S> map(Converter<? super T, ? extends S> converter);
}
```

You have `getTotalElements()` to get the total number of matching element.
`getTotalPages()` will give total number of pages.

Answer (score 14):

Use `result.getTotalElements()` to get the total number of matching element.

Use `result.getTotalPages()` to get the total number of page.

p.s. Use `result.getContent()` to get the content as List<>